# How to clone a deployment or application from existing project to a newly created project in openshift

Tags: openshift, devops

Is there a possible way to clone a deployment from an existing project(namespace) into a newly created project(namespace) through console or CLI in OPENSHIFT?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to clone a `Deployment` resource, you should be able to do something like:

```
oc -n source_namespace get deployment mydeployment -o yaml |
oc -n target_namespace apply -f-
```

But if you have multiple resources you need to manage, you're probably better off spending time creating manifests locally and then using something like [`kustomize`](https://kustomize.io/) to deploy it to your target namespaces.

Comment: is this a single lines imperative command??

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that question. I've suggested a command, and you can see for yourself what it looks like. The kustomize website has documentation on the kustomize command itself.